# Can add data but cannot delete

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I am trying to save and delete objects in a many to one relationship.

I have the following code

```
    [System.Web.Http.HttpPost]
    public void FollowPerson(int personId, int companyId)
    {
        var uow = new Uow();
        var person = uow.People.GetById(personId);
        var company = uow.Companies.GetById(companyId);

        company.People.Add(person);
        uow.Companies.Update(company);
    }

    [System.Web.Http.HttpDelete]
    public void UnFollowPerson(int personId, int companyId)
    {
        var uow = new Uow();
        var person = uow.People.GetById(personId);
        var company = uow.Companies.GetById(companyId);

        company.People.Remove(person);
        uow.Companies.Update(company);
    }
```

The Follow function works but the unfollow function does not.

The unfollow function seems to work, as it actually removes the person from the list but the Update function does not update it in the database.

My update function is

```
public void Update(Company company)
    {           
        var compToUpate = DbSet.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Id == company.Id);
        DbContext.Entry(compToUpate).CurrentValues.SetValues(company);
        DbContext.SaveChanges();
    }
```

Relationship within Company class

```
private ICollection<Person> _people;
public virtual ICollection<Person> People
    {
        get { return _people; }
        set { _people = value; }
    }
```

Comment: Please add relationship options

Comment: @ElvinArzumanoğlu is that what you mean? See update

Comment: I want to see relationship between People and Company class, please

Comment: Sorry Elvin, I have updated to show relationship. There is no relationship set in the Person class.

Comment: Is there any exception?

Comment: İ cann't see any infor between personId and companyId. Are They relationalinfo? Did you write DbContext.SaveChanges(); code in Remove method?

Comment: I have already added Save changes. I have received an answer below. Thank you for your help Elvin

Comment: It is not remove method and SaveChage():)). Not at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does this work

```
    var company = uow.Companies.GetById(companyId);
      ...depending on if you have lazy loading, might need to do a load on People
   var person = company.People.where(p=> p.id==personId).first();
   company.People.Remove(person);
```

EF is a finicky beast.